# HDMI to Display Port with a KVM and docking station

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, kvm-switch, display-adapter

I have a KVM with HDMI ports and a Dell docking station for my lapotop with DP ports. I used HDMI cables and bought [HDMI-DP adapters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081GMCNNF). It works fine 99% of the time, but for every hour or so the monitors attached to my KVM blink off for a second or two. No data is lost (if it happens during a Zoom I still hear sound on the speakers attached to the KVM and they can still see my on the webcam attached to the KVM). My monitors don't have Dynamic Refresh Rate, just 60 Hz, 59.94 Hz and 50 Hz. Is it the adapters that don't work and single cable with HDMI on one end and DP on the other would solve it?

Comment: “Is it the adapters that don't work and single cable with HDMI on one end and DP on the other would solve it?” - This question is confusing and not clear. Please clarify your question by editing your question.

Comment: See if I have this right ... you have `an unmentioned computer` ->  `KVM` -> `HDMI cable` -> `HDMI to DP adapter` -> `dell docking station`?

Comment: @Ramhound: yes - I'm wondering if it's the adapters that are causing the problem, and that i should just get a cable with the correct two ends.

Comment: @JaromandaX dell laptop --> dell docking station with DP inputs --> HDMI to DP adapter --> HDMI cable --> Startech SV431DHD4KU KVM --> HDMI --> Dell monitor